# HttpPost Not saving changes

Tags: asp.net, http-post, ienumerable

I'm constructing this view where the user can edit multiple item and save one at the time with the 'Update' button.

[image: Update Multiple Items]

**Problem:** I have trouble making the 'Update' button work. Here is the post method:

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Test")]

    public async Task<IActionResult> TestPost(int id)
    {

        var machinetoUpdate = await _context.Machines
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == id);
        if (await TryUpdateModelAsync(
            machinetoUpdate,
            "",
            s => s.MchName, s => s.StoreID, s => s.PUnit, s => s.Status))
        {
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +
                    "Try again, and if the problem persists, " +
                    "see your system administrator.");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Test");
        }
        return View(await _context.Machines.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
    }
```

**Update:**
Basically, this code is not working. I'm following a tutorial and trying to adapt it to want I need but this simple is not saving the changes done to any row.

It don't throw any error tho.

This is the code for the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Application.Models.Machine>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test";

}

<h2>Management</h2>
<hr />
<table class="table" asp-action="Test">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Serial</th>
        <th>Tienda</th>
        <th>Precio por Jugada</th>
        <th>Estado</th>
        <th>Update</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input asp-for="@item.MchName" readonly class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="@item.MchName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <select asp-for="@item.StoreID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.StoreID">
                            <option value="">-- Seleccione Tienda --</option>
                        </select>
                        <span asp-validation-for="@item.StoreID" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="number" max="10" step=".1" asp-for="@item.PUnit" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="@item.PUnit" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <select name="Status" asp-for="@item.Status" class="form-control">
                            <option value="0">Operativo</option>
                            <option value="1">Nuevo Item</option>
                            <option value="2">Reparación</option>
                        </select>
                        <span asp-validation-for="@item.Status" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                { 
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <input type="hidden" value="@item.Id" name="Id" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
```

Any help and what I might be doing wrong in the Post Method is welcome. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try

```
return View(machinetoUpdate)
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the input. I tried that and the error is this (mentioned in the post): InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type
 'Application.Models.Machine', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type
 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Application.Models.Machine]'.